# How do I set search option defaults in MS Excel 2007?

Tags: microsoft-excel, search, microsoft-excel-2007, find

I'm using Excel 2007.  Every time I do a search I have to set the options to search within 'Workbook' and look in 'Values'.  Is there a way to permanently set the default search behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

Excel doesn't allow you to specify what settings you want for a default in the Find dialog box. There is a bit of a way around this seeming limitation, however—at least a partial way. Excel remembers the last settings in the Find dialog box for the entire Excel session. (The settings are not reset until you exit and restart Excel.) This means that all you need to do is create a small macro that will set the settings you want in the dialog box.

See this [article](http://excelribbon.tips.net/Pages/T008802_Changing_Default_Search_Settings.html) for more.